# How to write SQLExecDirect sql statement with variables

Tags: c++, sql, mysql

I am trying to execute a sql statement in C++ using SQLExecDirect statement.  It looks like I've got everything set up correctly, but I'm receiving an incorrect syntax error.  My problem is in creating the sql statement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
 
int main() {
    std::wstring email = L"test@gmail.com";
    std::wstring strategy = L"TestStrategy1";
    std::wstring CP = L"C";
    std::wstring watchListDate = L"2023-04-08";
 
    std::wstring watchListString = L"test1-930,test2-1045,test3-1500";
    std::wstring create_date = L"2023-05-10";
 
    std::wstringstream result1(L"Insert into watchList(emailID,strategy,CP,watchList_Date,watchList,create_date) values(");
    result1 << "'" << email << "\',\'" << strategy << "\',\'" << CP << "\',\'" << watchListDate << "\',\'" << watchListString << "\',\'" << create_date << "\')";
    std::wstring sqlString = result1.str();
 
    std::wcout << sqlString << std::endl;
 
    return 0;
}
```

> output: 'test@gmail.com','TestStrategy1','C','2023-04-08','test1-930,test2-1045,test3-1500','2023-05-10')

A test program is available online at: https://ideone.com/ciGIEY

How do I get it to produce the whole sql statement?

Comment: Can you show us the actual string passed to SQLExecDirect?

Comment: The string is there in the code above.  For clarification:.  const_cast<SQLWCHAR*>(sqlString.c_str()) .... sqlString =  std::wstring sqlString = result1.str(); ... result1= std::wstringstream result1(L"Insert into watchList(emailID,strategy,CP,watchList_Date,watchList,create_date) values(");
    result1 << "'" << email << "\',\'" << strategy << "\',\'" << CP << "\',\'" << watchListDate << "\',\'" << watchListString << "\',\'" << create_date << "\')";... The variables are in the code.

Comment: I'm too lazy to put that together...

Comment: So don't mark me down, just move on.

Comment: My advice is to output the string after: `std::wstring sqlString = result1.str();` and look at it. If it looks correct paste it into MYSQLWorkbench or whatever other program you are using with your [MySQL Datatbase](https://www.mysql.com/) and see if it gets an error.

Comment: That does clear up a lot.  std::wcout<<sqlString outputs a broken sql statement. It looks like 'test@gmail.com','TestStrategy1'...)atd_date values (  ... meaning the sql statement is not being put together correctly

Comment: So your problem and [mcve] amounts to this code: [https://ideone.com/ciGIEY](https://ideone.com/ciGIEY)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I rewrote the problem per your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why, but the below code works.  I moved the Insert statement into the result 1 << line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
 
int main() {
    std::wstring email = L"test@gmail.com";
    std::wstring strategy = L"TestStrategy1";
    std::wstring CP = L"C";
    std::wstring watchListDate = L"2023-04-08";
 
    std::wstring watchListString = L"test1-930,test2-1045,test3-1500";
    std::wstring create_date = L"2023-05-10";
 
    std::wstringstream result1;

    result1 <<"Insert into 
    watchList(emailID,strategy,CP,watchList_Date,watchList,create_date) values(" 
    << "'" << email << "\',\'" << strategy << "\',\'" << CP << "\',\'" << 
    watchListDate << "\',\'" << watchListString << "\',\'" << create_date << 
     "\')";
    std::wstring sqlString = result1.str();
 
    std::wcout << sqlString << std::endl;
 
    return 0;
}
```